# how to execute jquery after user control loads data

Tags: jquery, user-controls, tinyscrollbar

I am using tinyscrollbar and need to run the tinyscrollbar_update() function after a user control runs a repeater to fill in an unordered list.  I'd like to be able to trigger the jquery call to tinyscrollbar_update after that control has completed execution.  Fairly new to jquery.  How would I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just add a literal control to the page bottom of the page:

> Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("< script text/javascript >"
>   
>   + "$(document).ready(function() {"
>   
>   + "$('div#whatever').whatever();"
>   
>   + "});"

Make sure you add the script file(s) to the head of your page (which might actually be in your Site.Master file.)

This will go in your .cs file, in the page_load module.